# Azure ACI container deployment fails when launching with Command line arguments

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-cli, azure-container-instances

**I am trying to launch an ACI container from Azure CLI. The deployment fails when I send multiple commands from command-line and it succeeds when I just pass one command, like 'ls'.**

*Am I passing multiple arguments to the command line in the wrong way?*

```
az container create --resource-group rg-***-Prod-Whse-Containers --name test--image alpine:3.5 --command-line "apt-get update   &&  apt-get install -y && wget wget https://www.google.com" --restart-policy never --vnet vnet-**-eastus2 --subnet **-ACI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that you cannot run multi-command in one time. See the [Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec#restrictions) of the exec command for ACI:

> Azure Container Instances currently **supports launching a single process with az container exec**, and you cannot pass command arguments. For example, you cannot chain commands like in sh -c "echo FOO && echo BAR", or execute echo FOO.

You just can execute the command such as `whoami`, `ls` and etc in the CLI command.

I suggest that you can run the command to create an interactive session with the container instance to execute command continuously after you create the ACI, refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237642/how-do-i-run-multiple-commands-when-deploying-a-container-group).